# Database Connectivity and setup of the application with the database

Tags: database, connectivity

Connection string to connect the SQLSERVER Express Database and How to take setup of that database with my application.....

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: What do you mean by " How to take setup of that database with my application....." ?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should get you started    .

```
SQLConnectionStringBuilder bldr = new SQLConnectionStringBuilder        
    bldr.DataSource = "Server"  //Put your server or server\instance name here.  Likely YourComputerName\SQLExpress        
    bldr.InitialCatalog = "MyDB"  //The database on the server that you want to connect to.        
    bldr.UserID = "SomeUser" //The user id        
    bldr.Password = "SomePassword"  //The pwd for said user account
SQLConnection myConnection = new SQLConnection(bldr.ConnectionString)
```